# Split string into list of non-whitespace and whitespace

Tags: python

I want to split a string into parts so that

```
Hello,  what   is up?
```

becomes

```
["Hello,", "  ", "what", "   ", "is", " ", "up?"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import re
x="Hello,  what   is up?"
print re.split("(\s+)",x)
```

You can use `re.split` for this.

Output:`['Hello,', '  ', 'what', '   ', 'is', ' ', 'up?']`

We can also use

```
re.findall(r"\S+|\s+",x)
```

This will not give empty string is there's a space at start or end.

Comment: It is interesting to note that if the text starts / ends with whitespace, an extra empty string ('') is added at the beginning / end of the list (at least with Python 3.7.2).
For example, if `x = "Hello,  what   is up? "`, the output is: `['Hello,', '  ', 'what', '   ', 'is', ' ', 'up?', ' ', '']`.

Comment: If you read comments carefully before answering them, next time you will not write such answers. I am not talking about whitespace, but an EMPTY string. See the last extra entry in the output in my comment.

Comment: @jciloa re.findall(r"\S+|\s+",x) try this.This will not give EMPTY string.

Answer (score -4):

Simply use `string.split(" ")`.If you want to eliminate those white spaces also then `string.split()`

Comment: He doesn't want to elimite the white spaces.

Comment: you also remove the white spaces if you do `string.split(" ")`. Try it and compare with the OP's desired output.

Comment: right I thought he wants to simply split string , but then this question splitting string while keeping spaces answered before.